# How to Disable the button while selecting the items in combobox in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to disable the button if there aren't anything selected in combobox? Here is my code that i have tried

```
if (satelliteComboBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    displayProductionDataButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

I have tried this but it is not working, i was very appreciate of any suggestion

Comment: _please give me the perfect answer_. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: What do you mean by selecting? Do you mean as the user is selecting?

Comment: if you check `satelliteComboBox.Items.Count` it is the number of items present in the combobox (so if there are items it would be disabled ), Maybe you should check the required field validators also

Comment: Have you written your if block inside the selectedIndexChange event of combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra item at first of  the collection of combo box ie "Select"  by default or on load combo box selected item should be "Select" ,therefore the selected Index of the combo box will be 0 ,so just check if the

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
 {
   //No item Selected
   displayProductionDataButton.Enabled = false;
 }
else
{
 //item selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you should set true the AutoPostBack property for DropDownList.
After that , in the SelectedIndexChange event you can use your desired code like this :

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

In this code when user doesn't select any item , the button disabled.
Or you can set your *First* item of DropDownList the value like 'Choose ...' and change the code to this,it's better for your users :

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                Button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Button1.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

tried

```
 if (satelliteComboBox.Items.Count is nothing)
   {
       displayProductionDataButton.Enabled = false;
   }
```

Comment: Arwin Zhang : thanks for ur answer but what i need is on selecting the item in combobox the button should be disable

Comment: Why you not use other logic?
Like, if your combobox select any item, then your textbox will having the text. Then if textbox have value, button enable, else textbox not have value, button disable..
code :
If textbox1.text = "" then combobox.enable = false
Else combobox.enable = true
End if